# Applying padding-top to style with border-radius breaks border-radius functionality

Tags: html, css

```
<img src="Image source here" width="132" height="148" style="border-radius:3px;padding-top:50px"/>
```

Can anyone post some clarity to as why adding `padding-top`, seems to cause the browser ignore the `border-radius` property?

You can do a quick test by removing / adding the padding from the style attribute, notice how **WITH** padding, the border-radius is ignored.

Is this a bug, or is there good reason behind this?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is because by adding padding top your border just go up (50px)  so use margin-top. 
like this (i add a background-color to see it better)

```
<img src="Image source here" width="132" height="148" style=" background-color: #3d3d3d; border-radius:3px; margin-top:50px; "/>
```

I hope it helps

look at it here  [codepen](http://codepen.io/wrostran/pen/pIbhf)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the box model mate, you should use margin-top here instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="132" height="148" style="border: 3px solid red; padding-top: 50px;"/>
```

**UPDATE:**
**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Shashi0812/GJ8Bt/

Comment: I still get border-radius ignored in fire fox for your example.

Comment: Your example does not even include, border-radius attribute good sir. Thank you for your time though.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, but after adding border-radius also, it works

Comment: Interesting, thank you for pointing that out.  It seems that border-radius will work on an actual "border" as you pointed out, but I was using it to round an image.  Thanks a lot, gave you an up vote!